# Strange output link in facebook api https:\/\/scontent

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

I have a following question: when I query facebook graph api with this:
`WWW www = new WWW("https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=picture&access_token=" + accessToken);`

Instead of getting normal link I get double slashes one of which is incorrect, like this:
`https:\/\/scontent (..)`.
All the slashes are affected ant it makes it impossible to display the image in the application. Can I do something to correct this?

Ok, I actually corrected this before sending the message, when I ask for picture?type=large it works correctly. Just out of sheer curiosity - what is the reason?

Full code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Connect : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Image img;
    public Text nameUser;
    public Text location;

    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(GetUserInfoWWW());
    }

    string accessToken = "<token>";

    IEnumerator GetUserInfoWWW()
    {
        WWW www = new WWW("https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,location&access_token=" + accessToken);


        yield return www;

        Debug.Log(www.text);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{"id":"295934407231059","name":"Magdalena Kowalska","picture":{"data":{"is_silhouette":false,"url":"https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-1\/p50x50\/16997833_724439017713927_4888848628170298878_n.jpg?oh=0a771cf0f72da28ba1787508dd372e59&oe=595A0F77"}}}
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
<GetUserInfoWWW>c__Iterator0:MoveNext() (at Assets/Connect.cs:27)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)
```

Comment: `string correct = link.Replace("\\/", "/");` - [online example](http://rextester.com/GVS11862)

Comment: @m.rogalski You got that backwards. The / does not need to be escaped, but the \ does, so it would have to be `Replace("\\/", "/");`

Comment: @NickWilson You're right. I have done it right in the rextester but put mistakenly here. Thank you for the hint, edited it :)

Comment: We don't see code so I doubt that anyone can help with these ( almost none ) specific details of your problem.

Comment: @m.rogalski Your solution helps, I just don't understand why just this output link looks like that:) I updated the question with full code, which generates the problem, but it's not much more than this:).

Comment: @MagdalenaKowalska The same thing applies to C#, you have to escape some characters. I think facebook escapes `/` character or it can be a bug from their side. And I would suggest you to renew your access token and don't use it publicly :)

Comment: Asking for `/me/picture?type=large` and `/me?fields=picture` are two different things. Only the first one responds with an HTTP redirect to the actual image location on their CDN, the second one returns a JSON data structure. And in JSON, the `/` gets escaped as `\/`. So _decode_ the JSON, and you have perfectly fine data with no “wrong characters”.

Comment: @CBroe That is exact answer (did decoding by chance some time ago, and noticed it help with that issue). Could you add this as an answer so I could mark it as correct? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asking for `/me/picture?type=large` and `/me?fields=picture` are two different things. Only the first one responds with an HTTP redirect to the actual image location on their CDN, the second one returns a JSON data structure.

And in JSON, the `/` gets escaped as `\/`. So decode the JSON, and you have perfectly fine data with no “wrong characters”.